# facebook fb:swf stops working when you load an as2.0 object in as3.0

Tags: flash, facebook

I'm using the [gskinner.com](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html) bridge to load and talk between a as2.0 object in as3.0 . The library works smoothly. If I upload the html it works smoothly.

But when I embed it as using fb:swf on facebook, the as2.0 object stops loading, any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
addChild(myLoader); 
var url:String = "http://flashtestapp.varheroes.com/as2.swf"
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
myLoader.load(urlReq);

Apparently fb:swf doesn't like relative urls, if I load the swf from the same folder it doesn't work but giving a absolute url does.